What would happen if the Mass were not celebrated worldwide on a given day?
For example, if no Mass were celebrated worldwide this Sunday, what would happen? Is there any teaching in Catholicism about this?
It doesn't necessarily have to be on a Sunday; it could be on a Friday, for instance.
Thank you, I hope you can help me. Hail Mary!

Padre Pio said: "It would be easier for the world to survive without the sun than to do without Holy Mass."

And to get an idea why St. Padre Pio, as as as other Catholic Saints  said the same thing, please, please read St. Leonard of Port Maurice's "The Hidden Treasure, or the Immense Excellence of the Holy Sacrifice of the Mass," found, for example, here: https://dn790001.ca.archive.org/0/items/St.LeonardOfPortMauriceTheHiddenTreasureOrTheImmenseExcellenceOfTheHolySacrificeOfTheMass/St.%20Leonard%20of%20Port%20Maurice%20-%20The%20Hidden%20Treasure%20or%20the%20Immense%20Excellence%20of%20the%20Holy%20Sacrifice%20of%20the%20Mass.pdf

What would happen if the Mass were not celebrated worldwide on a given day?
The Church would continue as usual.
In fact, each year the mass is not celebrated on Good Friday. The liturgy on Good Friday is known as the Mass of the Presanctified. No Mass is technically celebrated on Holy Saturday either. Any Mass celebrated on Holy Saturday is part of the Easter Vigil.

The Mass of the Presanctified (Missa præsanctificatorum) is Christian liturgy traditionally celebrated on Good Friday in which the consecration is not performed. Instead, the Blessed Sacrament that was consecrated at an earlier Mass and reserved is distributed.
The liturgy had developed by the time of the Quinisext Council (Second Trullan Synod, 692). In the Roman and Anglican Rites it is used only on Good Friday, while in some Old Catholic Rites it is used on both Good Friday and Holy Saturday.
In both the Ordinary and the Extraordinary Form of the Roman Rite, the term "Mass of the Presanctified" is not used in the Missal and other liturgical books, the ceremony having been retitled Solemn Afternoon Liturgy of the Passion and Death of the Lord (Solemnis actio liturgica postmeridiana in Passione et Morte Domini) in the 1955 revisions of Pope Pius XII. It is also called the Solemn Commemoration of the Lord's Passion.
The Divine Liturgy of the Presanctified Gifts is used in the Eastern Orthodox Church and those Eastern Catholic Churches which follow the Byzantine Rite only on the weekdays (Monday through Friday) of Great Lent, and on Monday through Wednesday of Holy Week. At each of these Presanctified Liturgies, the Sacred Mysteries (Blessed Sacrament) would have been consecrated the previous Sunday.
Mass of the Presanctified


Also Holy Saturday.  That is why Easter Vigil can not start until after sundown.

@Mary That is not why the Easter Vigil cannot start until after sundown. The Easter Vigil with its Mass was celebrated before sundown for centuries, including in the morning from around Trent until 1953-1955.

It's not celebrated so now.  The condition was a day without Mass.
